# Jetpack Compose - Room database not able to read from flow on release build

Tags: android-room, android-jetpack-compose, proguard, release

I'm performing an action on an item and using the copy function to update its value in room database. It works as intended in debug version (the text changes color/value) but in release build it doesn't. It still works, I just don't see it reflects right away. If I navigate away from tab and back I can see the state updates. Why it doesn't behave the same on release build? How would you go by to debug this?

```
//updating in ViewModel
repository.updateIsDisconnected(devices.copy(isDisconnected = true))

//getting * from db
val getItems = vm.getItems.collectAsState(initial = emptyList())

//Presenting Lazycolumn
LazyColumn() {

items(getItems.value) { item ->
Row(){
//Text that is suppose to be updated
if (item.isDisconnected) Text(text = "Disconnected", color =  Color.Green)
                        else Text(text = "Found", color =  Color.Gray)

                    }
                }
            }
```

I'm suspecting it has to do with ProGuard and I've added the following but still the same:

```
-keep class * extends androidx.room.RoomDatabase
-keep @androidx.room.Entity class *
-dontwarn androidx.room.paging.**
```

Comment: Same thing here, did you figure out what is the issue?